# Jackson - How to replace serialized Map

Tags: java, jackson

I need to serialize a graph to JSON containing List and Map. Each map instance contains a UUID field. The graph can contain more than one Map instance with the same UUID. Maps with the same UUID are considered identical.

During Serialization, I would like to replace map instances that have a previously been serialized by only their UUID.

What is the best way to achieve that with Jackson?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom serializer for your graph class.

You have to extend `StdSerializer` and override

```
@Override
public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
```

When you did that you need to let jackson know about your serializer. You can achieve that by annotate your graph class with `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)` or you could register a new module containing the custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working solution I came up with.

However, is there a more elegant way to get a lifecycle hook on top-level serialize calls (which is needed to re-init the custom serializer)?

Also, I'm not convinced that keeping track of visited objects per thread, using ThreadLocal, is the best solution. Any advices?

Thanks

```
public class IdentifiableSerializerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();
        test(mapper);
    }

    interface Identifiable {
        Long getId();
    }

    public static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // disable quoting - for testing purpose
        mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);

        // register serializer for Identifiable type
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Identifiable.class, new IdentifiableSerializer(mapper.writer()));
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        // lifecycle hook to re-init IdentifiableSerializer on root-level serialize calls
        mapper.setSerializerProvider(new IdentifiableSerializerProvider());

        return mapper;
    }

    /**
     * This class serves to intercept root-level serialize calls in order to
     * clean the map of visited objects, see {@link IdentifiableSerializer#visited}.
     *
     * TODO: this seems lot of code just to get a hook on root-level serialize calls...
     */
    public static class IdentifiableSerializerProvider extends DefaultSerializerProvider {

        public IdentifiableSerializerProvider() { super(); }

        protected IdentifiableSerializerProvider(SerializerProvider src, SerializationConfig config, SerializerFactory f) {
            super(src, config, f);
        }

        @Override
        public DefaultSerializerProvider createInstance(SerializationConfig config, SerializerFactory f) {
            return new IdentifiableSerializerProvider(this, config, f);
        }

        @Override
        public void serializeValue(JsonGenerator gen, Object value) throws IOException {
            IdentifiableSerializer.reset();
            super.serializeValue(gen, value);
        }
    }

    public static class IdentifiableSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Identifiable> {

        private static ThreadLocal<Set> visited = new ThreadLocal<Set>() {
            @Override
            protected Set initialValue() {
                return new HashSet();
            }
        };

        public static void reset() {
            visited.get().clear();
        }

        private final ObjectWriter delegate;

        public IdentifiableSerializer(ObjectWriter delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Identifiable value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            Long id = value.getId();
            Set seen = visited.get();
            if (seen.contains(id)) {
                jgen.writeStartObject();
                jgen.writeNumberField("@REF", id);
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            }
            else {
                seen.add(id);
                delegate.writeValue(jgen, value);
            }
        }
    }

    static class IdentifiableMap extends HashMap implements Identifiable {

        static long counter = 0;

        Long id = counter++;
        {
            put("@ID", id);
        }

        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }


    public static void test(ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map myMap = new IdentifiableMap() {{
            put("key1", 1);
            put("key2", 2);
            put("key3", 3);
        }};
        List<Map> myList = Arrays.asList(myMap, myMap);

        String expected = "[{key1:1,key2:2,key3:3,@ID:0},{@REF:0}]";
        String actual = mapper.writeValueAsString(myList);

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }

}
```